# how to put condition for ng-repeat

Tags: angularjs

I am using following `ng-repeat` statement.

Is it possible to put check in outer `ng-repeat` to say create this row only if 
student name (current iteration) is different from the previous student (previous iteration) e.g.  **but** continue to next `ng-repeat` to create additional cells for current row.

I am wondering if outer `ng-repeat` condition false than whether it goes to inner `ng-repeat` or not?

Before, giving advise to change data structure, i would like that someone please let me know if it is possible from front end or not?

```
<tr ng-repeat="student in students">
    <td style="text-align: left;" width="296;">{{student.FirstName}} {{student.LastName}} <small class="" style="color: #999999;">({{student.Role}})</small></td>
    <td width="100px" ng-repeat="subject in student.subject">
    <input ng-disabled="!subject.Enrolled" ng-change="savestudentSubject(subject, student)" ng-model="student.Checked" type="checkbox"></td>
</tr>
```

Comment: If the outer ng-repeat doesn't supply a `student` object then the inner won't do anything.

Comment: i believe that if you do use `ng-if` to conditionally show an element, `ng-repeat` won't fill that element with repeat objects.

Comment: you could use filter, and remove all unwanted elements from student

Comment: @immirza here you have some example with filter http://jsfiddle.net/TahmidTanzim/N9Vqk/ all what you need to do is implement filter which removes duplicates

Comment: I dont want to remove duplicates. they are all needed. probably i need to look some other way may change data structure or change HTML format

Comment: @immirza you want remove duplicates from array, you will just filer what you want to be passed to ng-repeat

Answer (score 1):

I think what you want is just the following:

```
<tr ng-repeat="student in students">
    <td style="text-align: left;" width="296;">
        <!-- Check if same student -->
        <span ng-if="students[$index - 1].id != student.id">
            {{student.FirstName}} {{student.LastName}} <small class="" style="color: #999999;">({{student.Role}})</small>
        </span>
    </td>
    <td width="100px" ng-repeat="subject in student.subject">
    <input ng-disabled="!subject.Enrolled" ng-change="savestudentSubject(subject, student)" ng-model="student.Checked" type="checkbox"></td>
</tr>
```

This checks if the current student is the same as the previous one. If it is, then don't display the name, but do display the subjects.

Or, you can just use a 'groupBy' to group the students with the ['angular-filter' module](https://github.com/a8m/angular-filter), for example by the same id:

```
<tr ng-repeat="(key, student) in students | groupBy: 'id'">
    <td style="text-align: left;" width="296;">{{ student.FirstName }} {{student.LastName}} <small class="" style="color: #999999;">({{student.Role}})</small></td>
    <td width="100px" ng-repeat="subject in student.subject">
    <input ng-disabled="!subject.Enrolled" ng-change="savestudentSubject(subject, student)" ng-model="student.Checked" type="checkbox"></td>
</tr>
```

[JSBIN](http://jsbin.com/xeloyukizu/2/edit?html,js,output) (bit hacky with the ng-repeat-start and -end, probably could be done better)

Comment: if the current student is the same as the previous one than dont create new row instead show subject name in the previous created row in new cell. Did u get me?

Comment: I thought he meant adding the condition on the outer repeat... otherwise this is the solution

Comment: @devqon, im getting error Error: [$injector:unpr] http://errors.angularjs.org/1.3.0/$injector/unpr?p0=groupByFilterProvider%20%3C-%20groupByFilter

Comment: @devqon, where i have to use angulatr-filter? i dont see in your updated answer.

Comment: Include the script and the module in your app